# Can't set a label in a view

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, view, uilabel

I have the following situation. I have a view controller (ContentController) with 3 buttons at the top. Below I added a second view (contentView), this view should display content that are behind those 3 buttons. So every time I press a button, the contentView changes. So what I did was created three addition controllers.

FirstController.m, FirstController.h, FirstController.xib

SecondController.m, SecondController.h, SecondController.xib,

ThirdController.m, ThirdController.h, ThirdController.xib,

in my ContentController.m I added 3 IBActions that handles the change.

```
@interface ViewController ()

@property (nonatomic,strong) UIViewController *nextController;
@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize nextController = _nextController;

-(IBAction)chooseFirstController:(id)sender {
    _nextController = [[FirstController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstController" bundle:nil];
    [self.contentView addSubview:_nextController.view];

}
-(IBAction)chooseSecondController:(id)sender{
    _nextController = [[SecondController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondController" bundle:nil];
    [self.contentView addSubview:_nextController.view];
}
-(IBAction)chooseThirdController:(id)sender{
    _nextController = [[ThirdViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ThirdViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self.contentView addSubview:_nextController.view];
}
```

My first and ThirdController just showing tableviews inside the contentView of contentController. But in my secondController I used a gridView for displaying items. Now when I press a cell, it should go to a detailViewController, whichs shows more information about that cell. So in my cellForRowAtIndex I did the following.

```
- (void)gridView:(NRGridView *)gridView didSelectCellAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSLog(@"cell clicked");
    PlayerDetailController *playerController = [[PlayerDetailController alloc]initWithNibName:@"PlayerDetailController" bundle:nil];
    [playerController setLblTest:@"hooray this works"];
    [self.view addSubview:playerController.view];

}
```

It correctly executes setLblTest and also showing the detailViewcontroller inside my ContentView. But it don't changes the label. to my @"hooray" this works. But although as you can see in my log it passes it correctly.

```
@synthesize testLabel = _testLabel;
@synthesize lblTest = _lblTest;

-(void)setLblTest:(NSString *)lblTest{
    if(![_lblTest isEqual:lblTest]){
        _lblTest = lblTest;
    }
    NSLog(@"log komt %@",lblTest);
    [_testLabel setText:lblTest];
}
```

**LOG**

```
RacingGenk[567:c07] log komt hooray this works
```

Hope this clarifies more my problem

Thank you

Comment: Is testLabel connected in IB?

Comment: What is your problem? I.e. what would you expect?

Comment: Are you sure this is the exact code?
I mean in the interface you wrote "ViewController". If you did not subclass UIViewController this won't even compile.

Comment: that testLabel is set with the lblTest string.

Comment: Another obseveration isEqual: is different from isEqualToString: which  is what I think you might have thought about.

Comment: See, you set it to `@"testtest"`.

Comment: @Daniel where do you see ViewController ?

Comment: @interface PlayerDetailController : ViewController

Comment: I'm always having fun when I see that IB gives people a hard time. I just then imagine 'how cool it is that one can create full UIs from code only and I use this terrific opportunity'.

Comment: @H2CO3 What do you want to say ?

Comment: It's not clear what your problem is. Where did the "hooray this works!" come from.

Comment: @SarahGeebelen I'm trying to suggest using code to make UIs. That would cause less headache than Xcode.

Comment: I'm getting this "hooray this works" from another view.

Comment: Then it sounds like it worked -- I still don't understand your problem.  What did you expect to see in the log? Where did you call setLblTest: from and with what argument?

Comment: @rdelmar I completly edited my question, hope this helps.

Comment: One more piece of info, if you please. What are testLabel and lblTest? Are they IBOutlets to labels?

Comment: No need anymore. I setted my label in my viewWillAppearMethod and it worked. But thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the label to update, you'll need to change your code to look like this.

`self.testLabel.text = lblTest;`